# Declaration terminated Incorrectly error in following code in cpp

Tags: c++, observer-pattern, compile-time

Iam trying to develop C++ program for observer pattern but i am getting these errors.
Here's my CPP code , and i getting error continuously : "Declaration termination incorrectly" !
Thanks in Advance
Help me please i am desperate.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Subject{
public :        virtual ~Subject();
        virtual float attach()=0;
        virtual int notify()=0;
};

class Observer{
public :        virtual ~Observer();
        virtual void update(int type, float amount, float bal)=0;
};

class Account : public Subject
{
public:  float attach()
 {
    char name[12];
    int account_no;
    float bal;
    cout<<"Enter the Name of Account Holder : ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter the Account No. : ";
    cin>>account_no;
    cout<<"Enter the Balance of his account : ";
    cin>>bal;
    cout<<"The Name of Account Holder : "<<name;
    cout<<"The Account No. : "<<account_no;
    cout<<"The Balance of his account : "<<bal;
    return bal;
}
int notify()
{
    int type;
    cout<<"\nMenu :\n\n1) Deposit\n2)Withdrawl\n";
    cout<<"Enter the type  for transition : \n";
    cin>>type;
    return type;
}
public: void update(int type, float amount, float bal)
{
    char name[12];
    int account_no;
    if(type==1)
        bal=bal+amount;
    else if(type==2)
        bal=bal-amount;
    else
        cout<<"Oops! Transition Type is invalild....";
    cout<<"\nThe Details of Account Holder after Transition     :-\n";
    cout<<"The Name of Account Holder : "<<name;
    cout<<"The Account No. : "<<account_no;
    cout<<"The Balance of his account : "<<bal;
}
};

class obpt{
public : static void main()
{
    Account ac;
    //AccountUpdate au;
    float balance, amt;
    int type;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"\nWelcome To The Program of Observer Pattern of Account Transition\n";
    cout<<"\nEnter the Details of Account Holder :-\n";
    balance = ac.attach();
    cout<<"\nCall notification for Deposit or Withdrawl Transition\n";
    type=ac.notify();
    cout<<"\nEnter the amount for transition : \n";
    cin>>amt;
    cout<<"\nAfter The transition the Main balance : \n";
    ac.update(type, amt, balance);
    getch();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `;` at the end of the class declaration. Correct:

```
class Foo
{
    /*...*/
};
```

In `C++`, `main` should be a free function, the `obpt` class is wrong.

```
int main()
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate which class you are talking about , coz i tried with the Class Obpt but it makes my _main module inaccessible

Comment: again same error is shown. "Declaration termination incorrectly"

Comment: Right at the end of class obpt {...} there is a missing semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you are receiving is coming from the compiler. It is stating that a declaration statement has not been ended correctly.

Somewhere in your code you are missing a semi-colon ; perhaps at the end of a class declaration or after a variable is defined.

Without seeing your code, there is no way for me to pinpoint the problem, but the error message should take you to the line if you double click it!

Regards, Rakesh.

Comment: But there is code inside the question. I do not see a difference between this answer and the answer from 2014.